# Convert ObjectId of mongodb object to string

Tags: django, mongodb, django-templates

How to convert ObjectId of mongodb object in string format.

```
ObjectId('5323d54c41cf6e0ffab13384')
```

I have above ObjectId and i want to convert this ObjectId back to string name from which its generated.  Is there any way that i can directly display name from above ObjectId in django template. Please suggest.

Comment: are you using a java driver?

Comment: am requesting to all stackoverflow users who always used to give answers to developers questions, i strongly believe that this is a great platform which helps most of the developers to solve their problems. But please don't disappoint developers by downvoting to their questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just get the string representation:

```python
ObjectId('5323cc2770fde63cf1146ba3')
>>> str(o)
'5323cc2770fde63cf1146ba3'
```

Also see the [documentation](http://api.mongodb.org/python/1.7/api/pymongo/objectid.html)

From your comments though you do not seem to have a full understanding of what an `ObjectId` is and I would suggest you do [some reading](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/object-id/) on that. Also read up on [documents](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/document/) in general.

What you *seem* to be asking, which is not how your question reads is how do I get the **"properties"** from an `ObjectId` you received after you saved a "document" or, otherwise in some form or another. You get the "document" by querying the database:

```js
var doc = db.collection.findOne({ _id: ObjectId('5323cc2770fde63cf1146ba3') })
```

And then you can access the "properties" of the document you received. So the resulting "document" you fetch might look like this:

```js
{
    "_id": ObjectId('5323cc2770fde63cf1146ba3').
    "name": "Neil",
    "favouriteColour": "Blue",
    "age": "Don't Ask"
}
```

An `ObjectId` by itself contains no *magic* information. It is a primary key, to a document that exists in the collection.

Comment: No , I want the name of this object in string format. Is it possible to find out from ObjectId?

Comment: @SunnyChaudhari See the last line there. The `str()` function just converted the Object to a string. What else are you asking. Some other property other than the ObjectId itself?

Comment: See first of all let me clear one point, When object is saved in mongodb it gets an ObjectId, So for example name of object is say 'Neil' when we save this name in database its ObjectId say "ObjectId('5323cc2770fde63cf1146ba3')" So, i want that from this ObjectId can we find out the name as 'Neil', not by querrying just directly on django templates. please suggest, is there any way ?

Comment: @SunnyChaudhari See the additional information. You might consider that your question cannot be interpreted as what you actually want to achieve.

Comment: Ok i got it, means in simple way its not possible because ObjectId is for the whole document. am i right?

Comment: The objectid isn't determined by the document name - it's how you would query for the document.